# Update Database Command Failed With System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'o') Error

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I try to update my database using the code first approach, I got the below error. The build was succeeded. I am using entity framework core.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'o')
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommandListBuilder.Append(String o)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(AlterDatabaseOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.<>c.<.cctor>b__83_5(MigrationsSqlGenerator g, MigrationOperation o, IModel m, MigrationCommandListBuilder b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(MigrationOperation operation, IModel model, MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.SqlServerMigrationsSqlGenerator.Generate(IReadOnlyList`1 operations, IModel model, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.GenerateUpSql(Migration migration, MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.<>c__DisplayClass16_2.<GetMigrationCommandLists>b__2()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'o')
```

I am using the 5.0.13 version of the entity-framework core. I upgraded the version but still getting the error. Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Are you adding a column in a table that cannot be null?  If there are existing table rows of data then you'll get an error.  Try setting the variable with the "?" operator... eg public int? age {get; set;}..... you can fill the exisitng rows with data once migration is applied, then remove ? from type and reapply migration

Comment: @AHoughton I have set all the variables with "?" but still getting the error.

Comment: dang im having this issue as well